# how to make a roll dice simulator

Tags: python, discord.py, simulator, dice

I created a roll dice simulator and I take yes or no from user if they want to roll the dice. So if anyone typed a wrong letter than I want the whole code will run again automatically.

I tried creating class, function, loop but its not working. I do not know if its my mistake in applying or there is any other method

Comment: Have you tried creating a simple console program to just do dice rolling? Generally, creating a simpler example can make it easier to conceptualise how to make a more complex version. If you're new to programming, that might be a good starting point.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code to get any reasonable advice.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to run from start - as for me it should be single command which gives random number and it finish job.